# WampSharp authentication

Tags: client, wamp-protocol, wampsharp

I try to use [WampSharp](https://github.com/Code-Sharp/WampSharp) library to connect WAMP v2 server but NotImplementedException fired during connection. onChallenge method of WampSessionClient class has no implementation. How can I response 'authenticated'?

Answer (score 1):

WampSharp doesn't support yet authentication, it is a WAMPv2 advanced profile feature.

WampSharp currently supports only WAMPv2 basic profile (which doesn't include authentication).

You are welcome to open an issue/pull request but it will take me some time until I can work on it.

Edit: Thanks to Badger's help, client authentication is now supported in WampSharp v1.2.0.3. See the following [example](https://github.com/Code-Sharp/WampSharp/blob/wampv2/src/net45/Samples/WAMP2/WampSharp.Samples.Authentication/Program.cs) which is based on this [example](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/blob/v0.10.3/examples/twisted/wamp/authentication/ticket/index.html).